# Return fields not specified while inserting a record

Tags: apex, dml, object

I have a simple insert method in a test data factory class. However, I noticed that in the returning record, only the Id and Name are returned. I'm assuming the name is returned because I have explicitly set it in when inserting and the Id is returned by default maybe?

Is it possible to get other fields returned (E.g. I do not want to set them explicitly as I need them to have the default values)

```
public static Something__c createSomething(){
        Something__c something = new Something__c();
        something.Name = 'Test Something';
        insert something;
        return something;
}
```

Comment: if my answer (below) solved your issue, would you please mark it "Accepted" so that others in the community don't lose time by opening a resolved question?

Answer (score 1):

In order to have fields populated on an in-memory instance of an sObject (e.g. a My_Custom_Field__c value on the "something" object instance), you have to perform a query to get that field's value from the database.  The only exception to this rule is, as you inferred, the Id field which is added to the in-memory sObject instance auto-magically once you perform the DML operation `insert something;`.

In your case you could, for instance, add the following lines between the `insert something;` and `return something;` lines:

```
something = [SELECT Id, Name, My_Custom_Field__c FROM Something__c WHERE Id = :something.Id];
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, apex sObject instance does not any field reference and default values, if you want fields and default values means you have to query the record.